Why my asset keep disapearing once i press play?
I have an asset of a chest on my project. I copied to use it throughout the map with different items. But when I test the game, the copies are not where I put them. In fact it came to my attention, when I interact with the chest, it's like all the chests are in the same position.
At first, I tried spreading the assest in the map to see if it works. I revised the script and there is nothing wrong there. Seems to me it's something on Unity.
CHEST
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using EventArgs;
    using Item;

namespace Chest{

  public class ChestScript : MonoBehaviour {


    public Interaction interaction;
    public GameObject itemHolder;
    public Item.Item item;

    private Animator thisAnimator;

    private void Awake(){
      thisAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Start() {
      interaction.OnInteraction += OnInteraction;
    }
    
    private void Update() {

    }

    private void OnInteraction(object sender, InteractionEventArgs args) {
      Debug.Log("Jogador acabou de interagir com o baú, que contem " + item.displayName);
      interaction.SetAvailable(false);
      thisAnimator.SetTrigger("tOpen"); 

      var itemObjectPrefab = item.objectPrefab;
      var position = itemHolder.transform.position;
      var rotation = itemObjectPrefab.transform.rotation;
      var itemObject = Instantiate(itemObjectPrefab, position, rotation);
      itemObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
      itemObject.transform.SetParent(itemHolder.transform);

      var itemType = item.itemType;
      if(itemType == ItemType.Key){
        GameManager.Instance.keys++;
      } else if(itemType == ItemType.BossKey){
        GameManager.Instance.hasBossKey = true;
      } else if(itemType == ItemType.Potion) {
        var player = GameManager.Instance.player;
        var playerLife = player.GetComponent<LifeScript>();
        playerLife.Heal();
      }
    }

    }
  }

INTERACTION
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EventArgs;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interaction : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject widgetPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 widgetOffset;
    public float radius = 10f;

    private GameObject widget;
    private bool isAvailable = true;
    private bool isActive;

    public event EventHandler<InteractionEventArgs> OnInteraction;

    private void OnEnable(){
        GameManager.Instance.interactionList.Add(this);

        }
    

    private void OnDisable(){
        GameManager.Instance.interactionList.Remove(this);
    }
 
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        widget = Instantiate(widgetPrefab, transform.position + widgetOffset, widgetPrefab.transform.rotation);
        widget.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, true);
        
        var worldUiCamera = GameManager.Instance.worldUiCamera;
        var canvas = widget.GetComponent<Canvas>();
        if(canvas != null){
            canvas.worldCamera = worldUiCamera;
        }
        
        var interactionWidgetComponent = widget.GetComponent<InteractionWidget>();
        if(interactionWidgetComponent != null){
            interactionWidgetComponent.worldUiCamera = worldUiCamera;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public bool IsActive(){
        return isActive;
    }

    public void SetActive(bool isActive){
        var wasActive = this.isActive;
        this.isActive = isActive;

        var interactionWidget = widget.GetComponent<InteractionWidget>();
        if(isActive){
            interactionWidget.Show();
        } else {
            interactionWidget.Hide();
        }

    }

    public bool IsAvailable(){
        return isAvailable;
    }

    public void SetAvailable(bool isAvailable){
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }

    public void Interact(){
        OnInteraction?.Invoke(this, new InteractionEventArgs());
        

    }
}

The chest on the right is the original

We need some more information to be able to help you, could you post your chest interaction code? The spawning code (assuming it's not done in the editor)? Maybe a screenshot of the different chests in the hierarchy and how they're all "in the same position"?

Are you using Destroy in your script? Also better share unity logs.

In the image, when on play, all the chests seems to be in the position of the first one.

I'd check the Animator, there's a chance it changes the items position. So basically I'd disable Animator component, if it doesn't help then I'd disable interaction.OnInteraction subscription, just to try to localize the issue.

Disabling the animator helped, the chests are now where i positioned them. But I didn't exactly understood the issue, how can animate them whitout they reseting their position?

In the Animation track used you need to set the Track offset to Apply Scene Offsets
